# Replace a number in an xml using loop?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Haven't done this kind of process in xml before.

I have these empty folders, called: `125,127,128`

and I have this xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
    <Metadata version="1.0">
        <CODE_OK>510</CODE_OK>
        <DeliveryDate>13/08/2018</DeliveryDate>
```

I want to replace the number between:`<CODE_OK>510</CODE_OK>` with the number that is each folder's name:125,127 and 128 and drop each new xml in the corresponding folder.

Comment: Learn to use Bs4, pretty easy. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I will check it out but can you suggest how to do this specific task?

Comment: Hmm, you are supposed to first do some research and show a honest attemp explaining where your are stuck. You really should read [ask], because as currently asked, this question is off topic on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

sampleXML = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
    <Metadata version="1.0">
        <CODE_OK>510</CODE_OK>
        <DeliveryDate>13/08/2018</DeliveryDate>
    </Metadata>
    """

tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(sampleXML))
for folder in os.listdir("YourPath"):                 #Iterate the dir
    tree.find("CODE_OK").text = folder                #Update dir name in XML
    tree.write(open(os.path.join(r"YourPath", folder, "yourxml.xml"), "w"))     #Write to XML
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the folders are empty and I should give them the modified xml after it has changed the number.Is this what your code does?

Comment: Why don't you execute and test the snippet...and make modification according to your need.

Comment: It says: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: It needs 'wb'  maybe

Comment: How to make the exported file formatted as pretty printed? it gets exported in a single line.